# "Shadow" and "high" strings in Uri redirect directly to browser in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have following intent filter:

```
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="myghost.com"
                android:pathPattern=".*\.html"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
```

It works fine in most cases, but when I open links containing "shadow" and "high" chooser is not called.

Anyone knows other magic words that work in same manner>

Is there a possibility to disable such behavior?

Comment: Did you try to reproduce this on another device?

Comment: You can reproduce it on every device (Nexus, Samsung, Genymotion, etc.)

Comment: @interlude Did You managed to reproduce it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is related to escaping `'.'` character.

Change `android:pathPattern=".*\.html"` to  `android:pathPattern=".*\\.html"`

`'\'` is used as escape character when the string is read from XML. You will need to double-escape it i.e. literal `'.'` would be `'\\.'`

Comment: But why only `shadow` and `high` words were affected?

Comment: Since `\.` is not a valid escape sequence, may be XML parser removes it and the pattern will be `.*html` which indicates, match any character until the first occurrence of letter `h`. After that it expects letter `t`. In `shadow` next char is `a` and in `high` next char is `i`, hence pattern match fails. I've detailed answer for pattern matching [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25680582/2083078) which might help you.