# android:pathPattern for single file

Tags: android, android-manifest, mime-types, intentfilter

I need to define `IntentFilter` for single file named `myfile.ext`. At the moment my manifest looks like:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:scheme="file"
                android:mimeType="*/*"
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\myfile\\.ext"
            />
        </intent-filter>
```

I have also tried other variants like: `android:pathPattern=".*\\myfile.ext"` and so on - but still it doesn't handle my file.

Any clues?

Comment: Nothing like checking an answer as solution where you commented that it didn't work.  Good Luck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Android Pattern specifics :**

- `.` matches any character.
- `*` matches 0 or more occurrences of the character preceding it.
- `.*` matches 0 or more occurrences of any character.
- `\` is used to escape special characters in pattern. `\` is also used as an escape character when the string is read from the XML file. Hence to escape special character in a pattern, double-slash `\\` has to be used.

**Issue**:
In this pattern `".*\\myfile\\.ext"`, you are trying to escape character `m` which is a normal character. Hence it does not make any difference. It is equivalent to `".*myfile\\.ext"`. The data uri part of intent is `file:///mnt/sdcard/tmp/myfile.ext`. The pattern is matched against `/mnt/sdcard/tmp/myfile.ext`, but it fails.

`.*` tries to match any character until the first occurrence of `m`, which happens to be the 2nd char i.e. `/mnt`. **Pattern expects the next char to be `y`, but it gets `n` and hence the pattern match fails.**

**Solution**:
For above path, the pattern `/.*/.*/.*/myfile\\.ext` works.

For `/mnt/sdcard/myfile.ext` path, pattern `/.*/.*/myfile\\.ext` works. If you are not sure the sub-directory level, you will have to add multiple `<data>` element with different `pathPattern` values.

```
<data
    android:scheme="file"
    android:mimeType="*/*"
    android:host="*" />

<data android:pathPattern="/.*/.*/.*/myfile\\.ext" /> <!-- matches file:///mnt/sdcard/tmp/myfile.ext -->

<data android:pathPattern="/.*/.*/myfile\\.ext" /> <!-- matches file:///mnt/sdcard/myfile.ext -->
```

Here is the [PatternMatcher.matchPattern](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/os/PatternMatcher.java?av=f#109) method used for pattern matching:

```
   static boolean matchPattern(String pattern, String match, int type) {
        if (match == null) return false;
        if (type == PATTERN_LITERAL) {
            return pattern.equals(match);
        } if (type == PATTERN_PREFIX) {
            return match.startsWith(pattern);
        } else if (type != PATTERN_SIMPLE_GLOB) {
            return false;
        }

        final int NP = pattern.length();
        if (NP <= 0) {
            return match.length() <= 0;
        }
        final int NM = match.length();
        int ip = 0, im = 0;
        char nextChar = pattern.charAt(0);
        while ((ip<NP) && (im<NM)) {
            char c = nextChar;
            ip++;
            nextChar = ip < NP ? pattern.charAt(ip) : 0;
            final boolean escaped = (c == '\\');
            if (escaped) {
                c = nextChar;
                ip++;
                nextChar = ip < NP ? pattern.charAt(ip) : 0;
            }
            if (nextChar == '*') {
                if (!escaped && c == '.') {
                    if (ip >= (NP-1)) {
                        // at the end with a pattern match, so
                        // all is good without checking!
                        return true;
                   }
                    ip++;
                    nextChar = pattern.charAt(ip);
                    // Consume everything until the next character in the
                    // pattern is found.
                    if (nextChar == '\\') {
                        ip++;
                        nextChar = ip < NP ? pattern.charAt(ip) : 0;
                    }
                    do {
                        if (match.charAt(im) == nextChar) {
                            break;
                        }
                        im++;
                    } while (im < NM);
                    if (im == NM) {
                        // Whoops, the next character in the pattern didn't
                        // exist in the match.
                        return false;
                    }
                    ip++;
                    nextChar = ip < NP ? pattern.charAt(ip) : 0;
                    im++;
                } else {
                    // Consume only characters matching the one before '*'.
                    do {
                        if (match.charAt(im) != c) {
                            break;
                        }
                        im++;
                    } while (im < NM);
                    ip++;
                    nextChar = ip < NP ? pattern.charAt(ip) : 0;
                }
            } else {
                if (c != '.' && match.charAt(im) != c) return false;
                im++;
            }
        }

        if (ip >= NP && im >= NM) {
            // Reached the end of both strings, all is good!
            return true;
        }

        // One last check: we may have finished the match string, but still
        // have a '.*' at the end of the pattern, which should still count
        // as a match.
        if (ip == NP-2 && pattern.charAt(ip) == '.'
            && pattern.charAt(ip+1) == '*') {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I defined the same intent filter and tried to launch using `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.DEFAULT -d file:///storage/emulated/0/myfile.ext -t type/text`. I was able to launch the activity with it. I had to mention `-t` parameter, without that it does not launch.

Comment: in my case mime type is:

      `<data
                    android:scheme="file"
                    android:mimeType="*/*"
                    android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\myfile\\.ext"
                />`

Comment: ActivityManager captures the intent information in logcat, while attempting to launch the activity. Can you share that logcat content?

Comment: >09-05 08:11:31.941      635-635/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
>09-05 08:11:31.941      635-635/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ CheckJNI is ON
09-05 08:11:32.511      635-635/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
09-05 08:11:32.531       78-217/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ START {act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/tmp/myfile.ext flg=0x10000000} from pid 635
09-05 08:11:32.551      635-635/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM

Comment: But the file pattern here does not match : `file:///mnt/sdcard/tmp/cellbox.db` with `myfile.ext`.

Comment: if I type any other type like `application/myapp` or `text/xml` it works, otherwise it doesn't

Comment: Actually `myfile.ext` is just example, in reality it is `cellbox.db` - so I'm using in real-life code `cellbox.db` everywhere

Comment: @ManishMulimani you were able to launch your application because it has a registered mimeType.