# Android pathPattern for files starting with

Tags: android

I have an intent filter that I want to match files that have *MYAPP* in the file name and have a *.json* extension.

Now there's plenty of examples of how to define an intent filter for a specific extension, but how do I also limit the path pattern to files that contain a specific string (in this case *MYAPP*) in the file name?

Comment: Please bear in mind that relying upon filenames, or file extensions, is an increasingly risky proposition. [Apps will not be using `file:` `Uri` values in the future](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html), and you cannot rely upon other schemes (e.g., `content:`) necessarily using a recognizable filename or extension.

Comment: I don't understand what that means. My app exports and imports its data through via json files, and I want users to be able to import these files by tapping on them in a file manager or Google Drive or whatever. The app then parses the json and determines if it's in the proper format or not. What is the downside to this approach and what would be the alternative?

Comment: "I don't understand what that means" -- it means that an `<intent-filter>` based on filename or file extension works poorly today and will work worse tomorrow. "what would be the alternative?" -- have an `<intent-filter>` that pays attention to MIME type.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. But the MIME type would be `application/json` which would apply to a lot of unrelated files, and I don't want my app opening all json files or users tapping on my app's files and having unrelated apps open them. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: "Is there a solution for that?" -- not really. For files that serve from your own Web server, you can invent a MIME type. And, of course, files that are more directly managed by your app you can handle directly, so having the user put files in magic places (e.g., `getExternalFilesDir()`) can help. You can also "pull" files (e.g., having the user pick a file via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`) rather than having outside apps "push" files (e.g., you implementing `ACTION_VIEW` for `application/json`).

Comment: And you are certainly welcome to continue to try to support `file:` today. I am merely warning you that this will not be a good long-term plan.

Comment: Ok, the purpose of me making this is to make it easy for users to open the file from a file manager or some other place without having to place it in a special folder (as they had to do now). If this stops working in the future, I'll deal with that later. Once I disregarded your advice on something because it was too complicated, and six months later I regretted it bitterly. :) But in this case, it's either not have that functionality or have it until a better solution presents itself. I will certainly pay attention to this issue going forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way, as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25680582/2631300):

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />        
  <data android:scheme="file" />
  <data android:mimeType="application/json" />
  <data android:host="*" />
  <data android:pathPattern="/.*/.*/.*/.*/.*/MYAPP.*\\.json" />
  <data android:pathPattern="/.*/.*/.*/.*/MYAPP.*\\.json" />
  <data android:pathPattern="/.*/.*/.*/MYAPP.*\\.json" />
  <data android:pathPattern="/.*/.*/MYAPP.*\\.json" />
  <data android:pathPattern="/.*/MYAPP.*\\.json" />
  <data android:pathPattern=".*MYAPP.*\\.json" />
</intent-filter>
```

You can then repeat the `/.*` sequence for every sub-directory you want to match, as in the example.