# Opening files from Google Drive in my Android app by file extension

Tags: android

So I managed to get my app to open files with a specific extension from file managers, but is it possible for users to tap on the file in Google Drive and have it open in the same way?
I mean I know it's possible, other apps do it but what would be the steps to do this? I'm not interested in my app being able to manipulate files on Google Drive in any way, just to have Google Drive "send" the files to my app the way file managers do.

This is the intent filter I'm using now, but it doesn't work for files in Google Drive:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.DRIVE_OPEN" />              
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xz9" />
    <data android:host="*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Try a `content:` scheme, for starters. You might also see if there is any particular logging from the Drive app, at the time you request to do something with an `.xz9` file, that gives you an idea what the full `Uri` is, to see if the file extension is on there.

Comment: Drive is not mentioned anywhere in the log. Instead it's ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW cmp=com.google.android.apps.docs/.projector.ProjectorLaunchActivity (has extras)} from uid 10072 on display 0 whatever that means. I don't know what a `content:` scheme is and a Google search returns something that looks crazy complicated for such a simple action.

Comment: That's launching an internal activity (`ProjectorLaunchActivity`) of the Google Docs app. Strangely, there is no `Uri` there, which I had expected. "I don't know what a content: scheme" -- that would be an alternative for `file:`, `http:`, `https:`, etc. It refers to [content published by a `ContentProvider`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/16/how-publish-files-via-content-uri.html), which is where [everything will be moving](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html) in the future.

Comment: Ah yes, *that* thing. I'll look into a content provider tutorial when I have time, but I have no idea why Google Drive will simply not do what every file manager does when you tap on a file.

Comment: As [we discussed previously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36669355/android-pathpattern-for-files-starting-with), it is probably using the MIME type, if it knows it. You might consider temporarily adding an `<intent-filter>` for `VIEW`, `content:`, and a MIME type of `*/*`, and see if Drive recognizes you. If so, you can examine the `Intent` that you get, and then see if you can come up with a more constrained `<intent-filter>`.

Comment: When I open the firel in a file manager, `intent.getType()` returns unknown_ext_mimeType although the format of the file is json. It returns unknown_ext_mimeType even if I rename the file to have a json extension.

Comment: Actually forget it, it's obviously beyond my level of comprehension and it's not critical, so I'll come back to this some other time.

Comment: "intent.getType() returns unknown_ext_mimeType" -- `getType()` returns the string `unknown_ext_mimeType`? How thoroughly bizarre. At minimum, they should be using the Web convention of `application/octet-stream` or something, IMHO. There's nothing much that you can do about that. But, you may want to look at the `Uri` (`intent.getData()`) and see what it looks like. If there is a file extension, then your existing `<intent-filter>` structure, using `content:` in place of `file:`, might work.

Comment: `intent.getData().getPath()` returns the file's path in the file system. `intent.getData().getScheme()` returns *file*... but this is all when I open it in a file manager and it's fine. The problem is Google Drive doesn't even consider opening it externally, it just shows the file contents as text.

Answer (score 1):

I tested it myself for my app. You need to add this `intent-filter` to your activity so your app can be listed when the user clicks on a file inside the Google Drive app regardless of the file's extension.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action
        android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <action
        android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />

    <category
        android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    <category
        android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:scheme="file" />

    <data
        android:scheme="content" />

    <data
        android:mimeType="application/plain" />

    <data
        android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />

    <data
        android:mimeType="text/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: This works but it works for any file extension and snu file type, regardless if it's suitable for my app or not. I tried adding `<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xz9" />` to this but it doesn't change anything. It will still open any file that doesn't match any other app.

Comment: @TimSim Why are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: To open files with a specific extension and no other kind. The app can handle if it turns out to be the wrong file, but I don't want my app to open if user taps on some random file that has nothing to do with my app.